# JQuery AJAX Lookup for searching

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, database

I have a text box on a web page and I wanted to write some JQuery, AJAX code so that when a user types some text into this field, it looks up values from a column in a database and beings back values that start with the letter(s) that they have typed.  As the user types more characters in text box the selection from the database gets smaller.  The user can then use one of the options to autocomplete their entry.  How do I achieve this and would there be performance considerations here?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: jQuery Autocomplete! Take a look at [this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

There you go.

Comment: Can you query a database with this?

Comment: Yes, it has remote or local lookup options. The remote would be an ajax call to the server to retrieve the results.

Comment: You can even cache the remote calls - which I literally learned right now. See the examples on the right hand side of that site. They show you how to implement the different options.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI's autocomplete.][1]

**Here's an example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').autocomplete({
  url: 'suggestions.php', width: 300,
  max: 10,
  delay: 100,
  cacheLength: 1,
  scroll: false,
  highlight: false
});
</script>
```

Here is specific example for C# 
http://jquery-with-asp.net/2011/07/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net/

If you dont want to use jquery . You can use ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_Simple.ashx

Comment: Can this be used with C# and does it use values from a database?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a really great tool that provides the lookup and provides access to other data elements as well.

https://github.com/nfosci/input-fetcher-dropdown

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)